# How to define a local file as a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, papaparse

I want to parse data in my computer using JavaScript. I use [papa parse](http://papaparse.com/) .

In PapaParse documentation it has been stated local files can be parsed by following code ;

```
Papa.parse(file, config)
```

In documentation they say **file is a File object obtained from the DOM.** How can I define a local file as an DOM object ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: yes but not clear for me. I need an example. I'm not that good at js. In API it is explained like ;

`new File(
  Array parts,
  String filename, 
  BlobPropertyBag properties
);`

I've tried couldn't get that work.

Comment: @bukowski — That code has the note "from XPCOM component code" so it wouldn't work for you anyway. Read the second paragraph on the page. The one starting with "File objects are generally". See also the "See also" section of the page.

Comment: I've checked all the directories you've suggested but I'm still unable solve my problem. I don't want to select and "input" a file. I want to define a file as variable. (like a text variable) and use that variable on parser. Isn't it possible to read files on script side and use them as variables ?

Comment: I'm stuck on the same issue. Did you ever figure it out? I just want the page to load data I have stored as a csv so I can display the csv data. This has nothing to do with Security.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that this is possible as it would be a huge security problem. Imagine someone could just read files from your computer when you load their javascript through your browser. You'll have to go with a file picker.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="csv-files" multiple>
<script>
  var handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    // do stuff with that file e.g. Papa.parse(file)

  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#csv-files").change(handleFileSelect);
  });
</script>
```

the above code uses jQuery to load the files when the file picker was used.

see [joyofdata.de/parsing-local-csv-file](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/) for reference. Concise explanation.